# Setting IE9's document mode with QTP?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, qtp

Looking for any ideas or suggestions on this.

I have a site to test and it exists in our test environment and production.  Most of my testing is done in the test environment, but a final click through automated test is done in Production.

My problem is the one noticeable difference between the two enviroments - The testing environment pushes IE 7 Document Mode but the Production environment does not.

Normally, I don't care.  In this case, the conflict of IE9 with IE7 doc mode causes some missing objects.  So, in my test environment I get errors that do not occur if the browser is set correctly.

Ideally, I know the IE7 Doc mode should not be pushed, but for reasons beyond my control, it is and there is no changing that at this time.

So, anyone know if there is a clean way to change the Document Mode in IE when I start a QTP test?

Comment: After loading the site use developer tool[press F12] to change the document mode. [Shortcut keys => Alt + M & Alt + 9]

Comment: Thanks!  The shortcuts keys will help.